# Sharepoint: Upload own top bar link html and override default top bar link

Tags: sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

In my company, we have more than 20 sites of sharepoint. However, we need to standardise all the top link bar in other 20 sites. Can I upload my html file for top bar link and override the default top bar link. I understand that I can manually can top bar link items but it time consuming. I am new in Sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all those sites have the same master page, edit it and add your html menu there.
Start here:
http://changecase.net/blog/2015/10/28/safely-customize-master-pages-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: I am not sure where should I put my html menu file in my master page. I had experience of Web Development in PHP. But I can't understand with Sharepoint and ASP.NET development.